# Android directory display not listing file types correctly

Tags: android, mime-types, android-file

I have code which attempts to open GPX files:

```
public void performFileSearch(String type) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = new String[]{type.equals("KMZ")?"application/vnd.google-earth.kmz":"application/gpx+xml"};
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose file"), DIR_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        Log.d("****File","Unable to resolve Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT");
    }
}
```

and it works fine for files downloaded on the device itself. But if a GPX file is copied from my Windows desktop, the file is greyed out on the Android listing, with an incorrect file type (see screenshot below).

Even with the same file (e.g. the 'ElmFarm' one in the listing shown), downloaded from the same server, it appears correctly if downloaded from Chrome on the browser. If downloaded from Chrome on Windows, or from Safari on iPhone, then copied to the Android phone  (using Windows file explorer, or via an email) it shows as type 'bin' (or 'csv') and can't be loaded into my app. If I use the 'Device File Explorer' in Android Studio, the contents of these files are identical.

What is going wrong here? Looks like a Mime type is embedded in the files somewhere, but where, and why are they changing?

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: Android itself does not know about that MIME type, presumably. In the cases that work, you are downloading from a Web server, and the Web server provided the MIME type, which got stored in `MediaStore` somewhere (again, presumably). In the cases that fail, there is no MIME type information included in the transfer, so Android just treats it as a generic file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have added a few more notes to my question. Basically the file has been downloaded from the _same server_ three times. Downloaded directly it's OK, when copied from Windows or IOS the type is incorrect. (I can't find any examples of MediaStore, except on your own blog, and that's in Kotlin - something new to learn for me!)

Comment: "Downloaded directly it's OK, when copied from Windows or IOS the type is incorrect" -- I covered that in my comment. The browser gets the MIME type from the server and teaches the `MediaStore` about that as part of downloading it. Files copied via a USB cable or other means will not have MIME type information attached, and apparently Android does not know about this MIME type natively (the way it knows about `application/pdf`, for example). `MediaStore` data is used by the files UI that you are launching, which is why you are getting different behavior.

Comment: So can I use the MediaStore somehow to set the correct Mime type? AFAICS there's no other way to set a type; from what I have read elsewhere, types should be automatically set from the extension or 'guessed' from the file content.

Comment: "So can I use the MediaStore somehow to set the correct Mime type?" -- only if you are the one doing the download. "types should be automatically set from the extension or 'guessed' from the file content" -- yes, but `MimeTypeMap` does not cover all possible MIME types. I seem to recall researching this specific one based on somebody else's question here, and being surprised that it was not supported, given that Google's big into maps and stuff. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`